# Is the maximum current of a wire related with its length?

Tags: power, cables, wire

Well, I Know this seems to be a silly question..

Note that the voltage drop and the delivery efficiency is not under consideration, just the maximum current limited by the maximum dissipation power of the wire itself.

Thanks.

Comment: R=pL/A, so the current being I=VA/pL

Comment: Sorry, I'm not talking about the current when a wire is directly connected to the power source, but the maximum current when a wire will not catch a fire(or the temperature rises less than 10C,20C... etc).

Answer (score 4):

If the wire is very short, then the heat-sinking effect of how it is mounted must be taken into account. Good heat-sinking will increase the amount of heat, that is the current flowing, to obtain any given temperature rise.

For a *long* wire, long enough that no appreciable heat flows along its length to the mounting points, the length is irrelevant.

Comment: To add the obvious, this is assuming that the wire is physically spread out. A spool with hundreds of turns of cable will need much less current to melt the insulator.

Comment: RIf the wire is in a vacuum the heat loss will be entirely through conduction and radiation (no convection) so a wire that is quite long may still be getting a lot of heat sinking from the ends.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany ... until it's 'long enough that no appreciable heat flows along its length'. I thought jms's picky response was better justified!

Comment: Not intended as a criticism, just something I'm running into setting up testing in a thermal vacuum chamber.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer : No

The current rating depends on how much power (Heat) your cable can dissipate, which in proportional to the cable surface area, which is in turn proportional to the cable's length.

To summarize, a longer cable will have a higher resistance (R=pL/A), and thus will will generate more heat (P = RI²), but this heat will be distributed on a broader surface, which will compensate.

Answer (score 0):

I would also say, No. Because each unit of cable dissipates its own portion of energy in the form of heat, it doesn't matter the length.

It then is a question of whether the heat can be conducted away from the wire at a rate greater than the heat being dissipated.

Power companies know this. They can move a little more current down their transmission lines in the winter than in the summer. They will even up the current further during ice storms prevent ice accumulation.

Comment: That is true for a horizontal cable in air, but for a vertical cable the air round will heat up and flow upwards. Therefore the maximum current for the upper parts of the cable is lower.

Answer (score 0):

That depends if it's AC or DC.

For DC see the other answers. For AC it is a little different.

Ignoring voltage drop along the line, i.e. a superconducting line, the alternating current in the line is still generating a magnetic field around the wire. The longer the wire the bigger the field.

You can think of it as the primary of a very LONG transformer. If it is infinite in length it's an ideal primary, and you will not be able to drive ANY current into it unless there is an accompanying secondary somewhere drawing a load current.

Comment: Sort of. IR losses are real, whether Idc or Irms.

Comment: @LanceBeasley indeed, but the OP specifically stated ignoring voltage drop so it's a theoretical question anyway ;)

Comment: Good point. I'm not a physicist but if the wire is a superconductor then it seems to me the question then boils down to velocity factor and maybe thermal noise? The universe will never let you have much of anything for free…

Comment: @LanceBeasley the universe and car dealers....  ;)